# Merge two separate sed expressions into one?

Tags: macos, regex, sed

I'm reading the `RealName` from `dscl` for various users. Depending on the user, the output can be one of the following two:

```
RealName: <name>
```

Or:

```
RealName:
 <name>
```

So I have `sed -e 's|^[RealName:[:space:]]*||g' -e '/^$/d'` to get just the `<name>` in either case. I'm new to regular expressions, so I'm having trouble merging the two expressions. Any suggestions? (Just doing it for fun. That command works just fine as-is.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Match a line that has only RealName: and spaces, append the Next line to the pattern space.
2. remove RealName: and the newline.
3. What's left, should be <name>

Since the command order matters, the next select-lines command that matches anything (`(.*)`) on a line that starts with RealName: will have "something interesting" after the matched regex.

4. Match all other lines starting with RealName: and do the same without newlines
5. delete empty lines.

---

```
sed -E -e '
  /^RealName:\s*$/{ N; s/RealName:.*\n//  }; 
  /^RealName:(.*)/{ s//\1/  };
  /^$/d
' ~/tmp/RealName
```

If the substitute command has nothing in the match field, it defaults to the previous select-lines command's regex.

```
/hello world/{ s//bye mars/ }    
<=>
/hello world/{ s/hello world/bye mars/ }
```

Comment: Doesn't this involve several expressions instead of just two? Is this more or less efficient?

Comment: If by expression you mean arguments to the -e option, then this answer merges two separate expressions into one with three commands. I used two separate expressions for Realname: <foo> vs Realname:\n<foo> because it's easier to demonstrate, write and remember. And what matters efficiency, I guess appending _N_ext line is "slow". But ^RealName\s*$ should be less expensive to match than than [:NRaelm\ ]*. So overall it should be faster.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the breakdown into what this does. I guess what I meant was semicolon delimited parts of the expression, not multiple `-e` options. It's more verbose but if it's more efficient then that's great.

Comment: sed is very fast in general. You don't need to worry about efficiency unless your input is very (gigabytes) large.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a lot shorter, but you could just do

```
sed -e 's|^[RealName:[:space:]]*||g;/^$/d'
```

the semicolon makes it a separate expression, but you really want to catch a multiline pattern, which is probably not as nice as what you have here, but [this](http://austinmatzko.com/2008/04/26/sed-multi-line-search-and-replace/) is a good resource.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Can't make heads or tails of it, though; I'm just starting with regex and unfortunately the command the author wrote is way too complex for me.